# How to make a Cython module only meant to be cimport'ed by other Cython modules

Tags: cython

I would like to write a Cython module that is only intended to be used by other Cython modules. So it will only contain cdef's (no def or cpdef). I have looked and looked, and found similar topics, but not exactly this one. Could someone please give a brief example? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To `cimport` a module, you need a [`.pxd` file](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html). There, only `cdef` level declarations can be present.

For the successful import of the module, the `.pxd` file must be found in the Python path as a `.py` would be for a Python module.

To distribute the module, the `.pxd` file must be included in the `package_data` argument of setup.py.

It is not easy to find good resources about this on internet and few projects actually provide pxd files. Cython itself bundles a number of them and those are of course importable without specific settings (libc and numpy are there, for instance).

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me out with a small example?

Comment: Yes, I have a cython code with installable pxd declarations here: https://github.com/pdebuyl/threefry